# Is the force required to push a wheelchair over a curb proportionally the same as to pulling it over the curb?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, work

I measured the force required to pull a wheelchair over a curb using a winch and a digital fish scale.  Is it valid to claim that this condition would be comparable to the force required to push the chair over the same curb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is valid to claim that this condition would be comparable to the force required to push the chair over the same curb but only in case if the pushing force and pulling force (in pulling case) vectors are collinear to each other, in the same direction and having the same magnitude that means the pushing force should act on the same line as the pulling force was acting before and you will get the exact same results.

Basically, it is same thing that to pull a block with some force or to push a block from behind with the magnitude and direction exactly equal to the pulling force (collinearly to the pulling force that was acting before, they both are the same cases) the acceleration of the block will come out to be exactly equal to as in the case of pulling the block.